# ¿'Por' vs 'de parte de'?

Tags: gramática, vocabulario

Esta es una pregunta breve, y supongo que tiene una respuesta sencilla y obvia.

Hace años una profesora de español hizo hincapié en que entre los muchos significados de "por" uno fue 'de parte de'.  Es decir, cuando alguien hace una cosa en vez de otra persona, o en favor de esta: "Cyrano recitó el poema por su amigo, el cual era demasiado tímido para hacerlo".

Hoy alguien me ha corregido, diciéndome que mi uso era incorrecto.

```
✗ Escribí la carta por mi jefe.
✔︎ Escribí la carta de parte de mi jefe.
```

Supongo que estaba equivocado, pero antes de borrar lo que mi profesora antigua mi dijo de mi mente, quería plantear la cuestión aquí.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según [Fundéu](https://www.fundeu.es/consulta/como-utilizar-de-parte-de-o-por-parte-de/), debemos diferenciar entre "de parte de" y "por parte de", si bien ambas locuciones comparten la acepción de "procedencia u origen":

> La expresión *de parte de* es ‘a favor de’ (*La justicia no está de parte de Pedro; Está de mi parte*), ‘**en nombre o por orden de**’ (*de parte del rey*) y también ‘por parte de’ cuando indica procedencia u origen (de parte de padre).
>
> Por otro lado, *por parte de* indica origen (por parte de madre), una parte de un conjunto (*La medida fue rechazada por parte de los diputados*) o puede ser un mero sinónimo de ‘por’ (*Hubo mucho rechazo por parte de los afectados*).

(En este último caso, "por parte de" introduce al agente de la acción en oraciones o frases pasivas.)

"Hacer algo **por** otra persona" (o sea, en lugar de otra persona, o en su nombre o representación) es perfectamente correcto:

- Escribí la carta **por** mi jefe (lo hice en su lugar).

"Hacer algo **de parte de** otra persona" tiene un significado similar:

- Escribí la carta **de parte de** mi jefe.

"De parte de" simplemente puede sonar un poco más elegante y menos ambiguo, ya que "por" puede indicar causa: lo hice por él, por su bien, o sólo porque me lo pidió.